# How to handle Odata?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, odata

I am using Visual studio, and have a connected service to Odata service.
But I am not sure how i can extract meaningfull items from this? 
How do enter the data within the odata service, and can i somehow scope my way
through different entries stored in this?

Answer (score 0):

Odata is best for creating and consuming rest full APIs. It helps you focus our business while building restful APIs

Comment: I am trying to consume or create data, but can't see how i actually can consume anything...  Some example code would be usefull here.